# Remove Div Style from CSS using code (GroovePages)

Tags: html, css, styling

I want to remove the badge at the bottom of my webpage using css. I don't know how to specify which div style I want to hide since it doesn't have a "class" label.

Please help me

As you can see I want to remove the sticky bottom footer that is identified inside the `<div style="...">`:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a code, not a photo of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the div does not contain a class or a unique id, then this can also be hidden by specifying some style rules through the style attribute in the css. Like this:

```
div[style^="position: fixed; bottom: 0; height: 45px;"]
```

The `^` sign will allow you not to specify all styles in divs, specifying only some.

Just add this rule to your css.

```css
div[style^="position: fixed; bottom: 0; height: 45px;"] {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; height: 45px; background-color: black;">It shouldn't be seen</div>
<div class="anyClass">1</div>
<div class="anyClass">2</div>
<div class="anyClass">3</div>
<div class="anyClass">4</div>
<div class="anyClass">5</div>
```

But you can be even more precise and specify a selector with an empty class attribute using pseudo-class `:not()`.

```
div:not([class])[style^="position: fixed; bottom: 0; height: 45px;"]
```

```css
div:not([class])[style^="position: fixed; bottom: 0; height: 45px;"] {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; height: 45px; background-color: black;">It shouldn't be seen</div>
<div class="anyClass">1</div>
<div class="anyClass">2</div>
<div class="anyClass">3</div>
<div class="anyClass">4</div>
<div class="anyClass">5</div>
```

Comment: @ForgedAffiliate, glad to help.